# JQuery Draggable - Odd Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable element that I am creating a clone of and dragging to a drop zone. I want the draggable element to be re-draggable once it is set down in the drop zone correctly.

The odd behavior comes into play when I encapsulate the draggable div within another div. When it is encapsulated, it will not set the clone element to draggable, so I cannot re-drag the element. However, if in the jFiddle, you remove the divs from surrounding the draggable div, the thing works fine.

Working:

```
<div id="draggable"></div>
```

Not Working:

```
<div><div id="draggable"></div></div>
```

I need to know why the encapsulation is fooling around with this. It seems like it would be difficult to build a meaningful thing with a problem like this because I want to have a sidebar containing multiple draggables similar to these. Since building a sidebar requires encapsulating all these draggable elements within another div, you can see the conundrum I've happened upon.

The jFiddle links below contain the Jquery, and such.

Here is the jFiddle that doesn't work rightly: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9pXzN/3/).
And, here is the jFiddle that works correctly: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9pXzN/4/).

The only difference in the one that doesn't work: the dome class div is encapsulated by another div.

Comment: If you move the outside div so that it ends after container it will start working. http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/9pXzN/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the draggable on blah and add the draggable to the clone that is appended in the stop block.
Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var i=1;
    var indexP;
    var blah

    $(".dome").draggable({
        revert: 'invalid',
        helper: 'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            var newId = i;
            $(ui.helper).attr("id",newId);
            indexP = $(ui.helper).attr('id');
            blah = "#" + indexP;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.helper).append("<br><span>"+blah+"</span>");
            $(ui.helper).clone().appendTo('#cont').draggable();

            i++;
        },

    });

    $("#cont").droppable({

    });     
});
function updateStatus (x,y,i) {
    var xPos = "#x" + i;
    var yPos = "#y" + i;
    $(xPos).text(x);
    $(yPos).text(y);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, now why can't I just reference it by its id?